# Processing Frames from Mediacodec Output and Update the Frames on Android

Tags: android, image, frame, surface, textureview

I am doing a project on image processing stuff. I receive a raw h264 video stream in real time and decode it using MediaCodec. I have successfully displayed the decoded video on a TextureView or SurfaceView. Now I want to process each frame, do something to it using OpenCV4Android and show the updated video frame on the screen. I know OpenCV has a sample project that demonstrates how to process video frames from the phone camera, but I wonder how to do it if I have another video source.

Also I have some questions on TextureView:

1. What does the onSurfaceTextureUpdated() from SurfaceTextureListener do? If I call getBitmap() in this function, then does that mean I get each frame of the video? And what about SurfaceTexture.onFrameAvailableListener?
2. Is it possible to use a hidden TextureView as an intermediate, extract its frames for processing and render it back to another surface, say, OpenGL ES texture for displaying?

Answer (score 3):

The various examples in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) that use Camera as input can also work with input from a video stream.  Either way you send the video frame to a Surface.

If you want to work with a frame of video in software, rather than on the GPU, things get more difficult.  You either have to receive the frame on a Surface and copy it to a memory buffer, probably performing an RGB-to-YUV color conversion in the process, or you have to get the YUV buffer output from MediaCodec.  The latter is tricky because a few different formats are possible, including Qualcomm's proprietary tiled format.

With regard to TextureView:

1. `onSurfaceTextureUpdated()` is called whenever TextureView receives a new frame.  You can use `getBitmap()` to get every frame of the video, but you need to pace the video playback to match your filter speed -- TextureView will drop frames if you fall behind.
2. You could create a "hidden TextureView" by putting other View elements on top of it, but that would be silly.  TextureView uses a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) to convert the video frames to OpenGL ES textures, then renders them as part of drawing the View UI.  The bitmap data is retrieved with `glReadPixels()`.  You can just use these elements directly.  The bigflake [ExtractMpegFramesTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest) demonstrates this.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.